# What's the equivalent of wglShareLists for Mac OS?

Tags: opengl, windows, macos

I'm trying to share lists between two contexts on Mac OS but despite my research I couldn't come up with an answer so far. I've found that NSOpenGLContext was able to initialize a context with a shared context but not to set it afterward.

What's the equivalent of [wglShareLists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Mac OS?

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/opengl-macprogguide/opengl_contexts/opengl_contexts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001987-CH216-SW7) is Apple's documentation on the subject.

Essentially, you can either create an `NSOpenGLContext` (and in doing so, specify the original context you want to share using [initWithFormat:shareContext:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenGLContext_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOpenGLContext/initWithFormat%3ashareContext%3a) or use [CGGLCreateContext](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGL_OpenGL/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGLCreateContext)'s `share` parameter. I don't believe it is possible to share resources *after* initialization.

This will allow you to create a *second* context that shares all resources with the first context (the one you passed to one of the above functions). You have to make sure both contexts utilize the same GL profile.

There isn't a way to construct an `NSOpenGLView` (which you are probably using) with a shared context. Instead you'll probably have to [swap the existing context out](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenGLView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), or use that context as the main one from which you create the shared context.

Comment: I'm only working on the OpenGL layer and I do not use any NSOpenGLView. I really must initiate this share context after creating it since both contexts aren't created by myself. Seems like I'll have no choice but to re-create this texture by myself although it's not very good performance speaking.

Comment: I looked around, and all Apple's documentation I could find discusses sharing only at initialization time.